# Display some value in select option and value different for insert in DB

Tags: php, html, joomla, html-select

I have a table with some values like this:

```
table CECO
CECO_cod     CECO_name
109003       APRENDIZ SENA
```

Then I try to display that info in HTML select like this and it works fine because it only shows
the CECO_name:

```
$db        = &JFactory::getDBO();
$query     = "SELECT CECO_name FROM CECO";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result    = $db->loadObjectList();
$CECO_name  = $result[0]; 

echo " <select id='CECO' name='CECO' >";
foreach($result as $CECO_name)
{
 echo "<option >".$CECO_name->CECO_name."</option>";
}
echo "</select>"
```

But what I really want is to show the CECO_name and the value will be  the CECO_cod, something like this:

```
echo "<option value=".$CECO_cod->CECO_cod." >".$CECO_name->CECO_name."</option>";
```

Solution:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT CECO_cod as value,CECO_name as text  FROM CECO";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();

$options = array();
$options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', '0', 'Select');
foreach($result as $row)
{
$options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', $row->value, $row->value." - ".$row->text);
}
$dropdown = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options, 'CECO_1"_"', '="_"', 'value', 'text');
echo $dropdown;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Joomla there are some helpful things that already exist in the API for you.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo(); //
$query = $db->getQuery(true); // the true param clears the query and gets a new object

$query->select('CECO_cod', 'CECO_name');
$query->from('#__CECO'); // this is assuming your table has a prefix.

$db->setQuery($query); // set the query object to the DB object

$list = $db->loadObjectList(); // this gives you an array of objects
```

Now that you have an array of objects you can actually use JHTML to render an HTML list. 
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/html/select.php#L81

So you'll do:

```
echo JHtmlSelect::genericlist($list, 'my list', 'CECO_cod', 'CECO_name');
/* note the parameters at the end denote the 'value' 
*  and 'text' part of the select list. 
*  You might need to play with this a bit.
*/
```

That should generate the select list for you and is a bit cleaner than looping through and building the select list your self.

Also you might consider using using JForm to build your select list. Not sure what you're doing but I'd recommend it to make your life as simple as possible.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, I search about JHtmlSelect::genericlist and now works fine.
I will post the solution in original code.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to select both fields to have access to the data in the returned object.

```
$query     = "SELECT CECO_cod, CECO_name FROM CECO";
```

Then you could have the information needed retrieved in your select box:

```
<?php
/* create new database object */
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "so");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* query for all of the needed data */
$query = "SELECT CECO_cod,CECO_name FROM CECO";

/* begin select */
echo "<select id=\"CECO\" name=\"CECO\" >";

/* check to make sure we have a result from the query */
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    /* if we have a result we can populate the select data */
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        echo "<option value=".$obj->CECO_cod." >".$obj->CECO_name."</option>";
    }
    /* if we failed for some reason, most likely the query was to blame */
} else {
    echo "error, query was not successful.<br>";
    }

    echo "</select>";

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

I tested this code locally for correctness, please notice how it is all commented and I encourage you to do the same no matter how short or long the code your writing is.

Comment: Thanks but your code don't works because I use joomla database object.